Geopandas slow after vectorization
Processed an NDVI, created classes from it and vectorized the file.
The area is about 4 km * 4 km. I wanted to intersect, and that was slow. While creating a minimal example, it seems like any geo-operation is slow! I have never encountered such a slow behavior, in my years of using GeoPandas.
Minimal example:
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path

ndvi_gdf_path = Path(r"D:\mypath\ndvi_gdf.gpkg")
ndvi_gdf = gpd.read_file(ndvi_gdf_path, engine="pyogrio", use_arrow=True)
ndvi_gdf.plot(column="category")

non_green_areas = ndvi_gdf[ndvi_gdf.category==0]
len(non_green_areas)

non_green_areas = ndvi_gdf[ndvi_gdf.category==0]
len(non_green_areas)  # 79832

non_green_areas_reduced = non_green_areas[non_green_areas.area > 250]
non_green_areas_reduced # 390 rows

non_green_areas_reduced.crs  #epsg:25832

non_green_areas_reduced.geometry.buffer(-1.25)  # did not complete while writing this...

Hence, buffering 390 polygons, does not finish.
Versions:
numpy      : 1.26.3
pandas     : 2.2.2
pyproj     : 3.6.1
shapely    : 2.0.4
fiona      : 1.9.6
geoalchemy2: None
geopy      : None
matplotlib : 3.9.0
mapclassify: None
pygeos     : None
pyogrio    : 0.7.2
psycopg2   : None
pyarrow    : 16.1.0
rtree      : None

Edit:
Data can be found for few days on WeTransfer.
I even cannot:
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path

ndvi_gdf_path = Path(r"D:\mypath\ndvi_gdf.gpkg")
non_green_areas_reduced = gpd.read_file(ndvi_gdf_path, engine="pyogrio", use_arrow=True)

non_green_areas_reduced.geometry.buffer(0)


Not much to see based on your script. Could you share the data?

@Pieter added a link for wetransfer valid for 3 days. I used the file with 390 polygons, but it is still 80 mb large. Because it is the smaller file, opening it and buffering is enough to show the problem.

I had a look, and I can confirm the extreme slowness.
It seems that the NDVI image was 20cm resolution, leading in this case to most of the 390 polygons having at least 1.000 coordinates, with the largest even having 4 million. So in my experience performance issues are to be expected. Once polygons have more than 1.000 coordinates processing tends to slow down... and over 20.000 performance often becomes really problematic for larger datasets.
In my experience with segmentation of very high resolution images you can avoid many problems by:

simplifying the polygons before doing further processing, including removing very small polygons, small islands,...
working with smaller tiles (I typically use ~4000x4000 pixels)
don't use a higher image resolution than needed (e.g. resample the 0.2 meter to 0.4 meter pixel size if that is sufficient)

You could have a look at geofileops, pygeoops and orthoseg. These are libraries I develop mainly in the context of processing this kind of data.

It works, with downsample the raster from 20 cm, to 1 m resolution, or simiplify to 5 m. thanks!
